# microsoft graph: Get infos of all my licenses from all my domains

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'd like to ask if anyone knows if Microsoft Graph give us the possibility (even if beta) to get all the licenses from the users in all the domains I manage in my partner portal.

For now I use : GET /users (beta) + GET /subscribedSkus to get a list of all the licenses from my domain.

But the thing is that I manage more domains than mine for my customers with the partner portal and the info that matters for me is their data.

Is there a way to get this data without having to login with each of their admin accounts ?

Example:

my domain, smth@example.onmicrosoft.com (Partner) (3 Users)

customer domain 1, smth@customer1.onmicrosoft.com (15 Users

customer domain 2, smth@customer2.onmicrosoft.com (32 Users)

customer domain 3, smth@customer3.onmicrosoft.com (8 Users)

With Microsoft Graph, I'd like to login with my smth@example.onmicrosoft.com and get the info of the licenses of all the domains I manage (58 Users). But right now I only get the info of my own domain (3 Users).

Edit: added the example part.

Comment: Thanks Fabio there is way using powershell script to call graph api for each domain to pull all assigned licenses for logged users  `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,displayName,assignedLicenses,assignedPlans` and use [invoke rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure, does the Powershell API provide more commands or do you mean [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta) same command  ?
If so, I'm already using it and that's where I have a problem cause I can only get the licenses of the users in my domain but not the users of my tenants. I'm gonna edit my original post to help clarify a bit @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to sign in once and access more than one domain at the moment. However, if you know the list of domains ahead of time, you could provision a mult-tenant and and set an app-only credential for your app and then sign in to PowerShell using the app-only credential (e.g. `Connect-AzureAd` if you're using `AzureAD` module or `Connect-MgGraph` if you're using ms graph powershell module). So you'd have an outer loop in your script that would for each tenant sign in using the local credential (hopefully a certificate and not a symmetric key!). The reason to use app-only is then you won't have to provide interactive credential challenge response, it can be fully automated. However, it does mean you need to provision the system that runs the scripts with access to the secret for the app.